# Coffeescript class find or create mongo document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, coffeescript, mongojs

I'm trying to write a coffeescript class that when constructing a new object from it, it checks to see if an ID was passed. If so, try to find a document matching and populate object from that. If no ID is passed, generate a new ID an create a new document. I'm using `mongojs` to connect to my mongodb. However when I create a new object from the TestObject class, it throws an error that the collection name needs to be a string. I set @collection as a string on that class so I console.log the @collection property and its undefined. Whats going on here and how can I make this work?

```
class MongoObject
    @collection
    constructor: (id) ->
        @_id = if typeof id is 'undefined' then require('node-uuid').v4() else id
        @db = require('mongojs') config.mongo_server, [@collection]

        @db[@collection].findOne
            _id: @_id,
            (error, story) ->
                # Matching document found. Import data from document
                if not error and story
                    for field, value of story
                        @[field] = value if field is not '_id'

                # Matching document not found. Creating new one
                if not error and not story
                    @db[@collection].save
                        id: @id

                # Error occured
                if error and not story
                    console.error error

                return

class TestObject extends MongoObject
    @collection = 'TestObjects'
    constructor: (id) ->
        super('TestObject')
```

**Edit**

Rereading my code its clear that its an issue with the constructor and @collection being undefined in MongoObject. Is there a better approach to doing this? I could create a `setupDB` method and call that in each class's constructor that extends MongoObject after the super call but not what I was hoping for.

**Edit 2**

I revised my code. However I'm now getting an error that `constructor` is undefined. When I looked at the compiled javascript its pointing to `constructor;` at the top of the MongoObject code. Oddly enough coffeescript didn't put `var constructor;` which is normally what happens. I've posted the translated javascript just for reference

**Coffeescript**

```
class MongoObject
    collection: undefined
    constructor: (id) ->
        @_id = if typeof id is 'undefined' then require('node-uuid').v4() else id
        @db = require('mongojs') config.mongo_server, [@collection]

        @db[@collection].findOne
            _id: @_id,
            (error, story) ->
                # Matching document found. Import data from document
                if not error and story
                    for field, value of story
                        @[field] = value if field is not '_id'

                # Matching document not found. Creating new one
                if not error and not story
                    @db[@collection].save
                        id: @id

                # Error occured
                if error and not story
                    console.error error

                return

class TestObject extends MongoObject
    collection = 'TestObjects'
    constructor: (id) ->
        super('TestObject')
```

**Javascript**

```
MongoObject = (function() {
  MongoObject.prototype.collection = void 0;

  function MongoObject(id) {
    this._id = typeof id === 'undefined' ? require('node-uuid').v4() : id;
    this.db = require('mongojs')(config.mongo_server, [this.collection]);
    this.db[this.collection].findOne({
      _id: this._id
    }, function(error, story) {
      var field, value;
      if (!error && story) {
        for (field in story) {
          value = story[field];
          if (field === !'_id') {
            this[field] = value;
          }
        }
      }
      if (!error && !story) {
        this.db[this.collection].save({
          id: this.id
        });
      }
      if (error && !story) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  }

  return MongoObject;

})();

TestObject = (function(_super) {
  var collection;

  __extends(TestObject, _super);

  collection = 'TestObjects';

  function TestObject(id) {
    TestObject.__super__.constructor.call(this, 'TestObject');
  }

  return TestObject;

})(MongoObject);
```

**Edit 3**

Updated my code per my comments. Its saying that `@constructor.collection` is undefined in

```
@db[@constructor.collection].save
    id: @id
```

I assume its because its in the callback function of save. One step foward, two steps back.

**Revised code**

```
class MongoObject
    @collection
    constructor: (id) ->
        @_id = if typeof id is 'undefined' then require('node-uuid').v4() else id
        @db = require('mongojs') config.mongo_server, [@constructor.collection]

        @db[@constructor.collection].findOne
            _id: @_id,
            (error, story) ->
                # Matching document found. Import data from document
                if not error and story
                    for field, value of story
                        @[field] = value if field is not '_id'

                # Matching document not found. Creating new one
                if not error and not story
                    @db[@constructor.collection].save
                        id: @id

                # Error occured
                if error and not story
                    console.error error

                return

class TestObject extends MongoObject
    @collection: 'TestObjects'
    constructor: (id) ->
        super('TestObject')
```

Comment: What do you expect `collection = 'TestObjects'` to do and why are you doing `super('TestObjects')` in the constructor?

Comment: super is being called to run the constructor of its parent class. super is used in python the same way. http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html "In practice, this will have exactly the same effect as invoking super in Ruby or Python, invoking the overridden inherited function." I want to invoke the parent constructor logic first

Comment: Ultimately I want a base class that has the db connection code in it and each extending class to define its collection name so @db will point the right collection per each classes definition. so I'm not duping code again and again.

Comment: I know what `super` does but why are you calling it with a string and why are you saying `collection = ...` rather than `collection: ...`? `p = ...` and `p: ...` mean entirely different things. If you `collection` to be a class property then say `@collection: ...` and reference it as `@constructor.collection` in instance methods.

Comment: Typo on the = vs :. I was calling it with a string honestly because that's how its listed in the link I posted in a previous comment. I updated my code to use `@collection` and `@constructor.collection` and fixed the =/: issue. Now getting error that @constructor.collection is undefined but not the first reference to it, the third while in the constructor. I've updated my issue.

Comment: Well, the basic structure works (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PTLVN/), perhaps `findOne` uses a different `@` than you're expecting, maybe you should be using [`=>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) to define that callback.

Comment: => was the issue or I should say fix. Its not inserting in to mongo but that is a completely different issue all together!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about the meaning of `@` at the class level. A simplified example should help, this CoffeeScript:

```
class B
    @p: 'b'
```

is the same as this JavaScript:

```
var B = (function() {
  function B() {}
  B.p = 'b';
  return B;
})();
```

So you can see that `p` is a class property that is directly attached to the `C` class/function. But when you're inside a method, such as `constructor`, `@` refers to the instance so, in your case, `@collection` will be `undefined` because you're defining `collection` as a class property.

You probably want `collection` to be an instance property:

```
class MongoObject
    collection: undefined
    constructor: (id) ->
        # @collection is what you expect it to be in here

class TextObject extends MongoObject
    collection: 'TextObject'
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TzK5E/

Alternatively, you can keep `collection` as a class property and reference it through [`@constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor):

```
class MongoObject
    @collection: undefined
    constructor: (id) ->
        # @constructor.collection is what you expect it to be in here

class TextObject extends MongoObject
    @collection: 'TextObject'
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wLjz3/

Comment: That definitely works. I really thought it would be a class variable since its set for the class and any objects created from it. Instance variables I think of variables for the objects created from the class and are unique from each other. Good to learn new stuff though.

Comment: It is a class variable but you have to reference the "class" as `@constructor` inside an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to use slightly different syntax to reference the `collection` name:

```
class MongoObject
    @collection 
    constructor: (id) ->
       alert @constructor.collection


class TestObject extends MongoObject
    @collection = 'TestObjects'
    constructor: (id) ->
        super('TestObject')

t = new TestObject
```

Alerts `"TestObjects"`

The key is the use of `@constructor.collection`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up with

```
class MongoObject
    @collection
    constructor: (id) ->
        @_id = if typeof id is 'undefined' then require('node-uuid').v4() else id
        @db = require('mongojs') config.mongo_server, [@constructor.collection]

        @db[@constructor.collection].findOne
            _id: @_id,
            (error, doc) =>
                # Matching document found. Import data from document
                if not error and doc
                    console.log 'Document found. Updating.'
                    for field, value of doc
                        @[field] = value if field is not '_id'

                # Matching document not found. Creating new one
                if not error and not doc
                    console.log 'No document found. Creating.'
                    @db[@constructor.collection].save
                        _id: @_id

                # Error occured
                if error and not doc
                    console.error error

                return

class TestObject extends MongoObject
    @collection: 'TestObjects'
```